# How to find all hard links to a given file?

Tags: linux, hard-link

How can we find all hard links to a given file?
I.e., find all other hard links to the same file, given a hard link?

Does filesystem keep track of the hard links to a file?

The inode of a file only stores the number of hard links to the file, but not the hard links, right?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

If the given file is called `/path/to/file` and you want to find all hard links to it that exist under the current directory, then use:

```
find . -samefile /path/to/file
```

The above was tested on GNU find.  Although `-samefile` is [not POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/utilities/find.html), it is also supported by [Mac OSX find](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html) and [FreeBSD find](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=find%281%29&sektion=).

#### Documentation

From GNU `man find`:

> -samefile name
>        File refers to the same inode as name.   When -L is in effect, this can include symbolic links.

#### Differences between find and ls

`ls -l` lists the number of hard links to a file or directory.  For directories, this number is larger than the number of results shown by `find . -samefile`.  The reason for this is explained in the [GNU find manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html):

> A directory normally has at least two hard links: the entry named in
> its parent directory, and the `.` entry inside of the directory. If a
> directory has subdirectories, each of those also has a hard link
> called `..` to its parent directory.
>
> The `.` and `..` directory entries are not normally searched unless they
> are mentioned on the find command line.

In sum, `ls -l` counts the `.` and `..` directories as separate hard links but `find . -samefile` does not.

Comment: The result of this query is incomplete for users lacking privileges on the directories that contain the hard links.

Comment: Of course. You're listing entries in directories. You need read access to those directories in order to list them.

Comment: What could be a reason for the following behaviour? `ls -al` shows `var/www/html/logs` to have 4 links to it. I run `find / -samefile /var/www/html/logs` as user `root` and it shows me only one entry, not 4... what gives?

Comment: @pgr As counted by `ls -al`, every directory has a minimum of two links: itself and `.`.  In addition, if it has subdirectories, then every subdirectory has a file `..` that is a hard link back to its parent directory.   Thus, according to `ls -al`, a directory with two subdirectories has a total of four hard links.  By contrast, `find / -samefile` does not include the `.` and `..` directories in its count.

Comment: @pgr I just this documented online and updated the answer to include the information.  Thanks for mentioning this!

Comment: Thank _you_ for the extra info, very useful. For me, this raises an additional question - how to find which files/dirs have links _that I should care about_ (as opposed to default ones), and which are they exactly? Maybe answering those questions is too complex for a one-liner, and would require a script.

Comment: Expanding on John1024's answer, here's a script which lists all the files that have multiple hardlinks with a counter in first column, the inode-nr in the second, and other 'ls' output at the end, helping to determine the scope of the hardlinks [[[
find ./ -type f -exec find . -samefile {} -ls \; | sort -rn | uniq -c | sort -rn ]]]