# find all hard linked files between two directories

Tags: find, hard-link

How do I find if any files among two or more directories are hard linked?  In other words, do any files under two or more directories refer to the same file?

Similar to [How to find all hard links to a given file? [duplicate]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/201920/21203) and [List all files with the same inode number?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/73538/21203).  However, I'm wondering how to search for *any* hardlinked files *among different directories*.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `find` to list the inode number of all files in the directories that have more than 1 link, then sort the result and extract the lines where the same inode appears more than once.

The directories should be on the same filesystem:

```
find dir1 dir2 ... -xdev -type f -links +1 -printf '%i %p\n' |
sort -n -k1,1 |
awk '{   same = ($1==last)
         if(!same)save = $0
         else{ if(save!=""){ print save; save = "" }
                print 
         }
         last = $1
}'
```

This code prints the files and their inode.

```
108743 /tmp/a1
108743 /tmp/a2-hardlink-to-a1
```

If `find` is not available then use `ls -i1`.

Answer (score 1):

This `find` command should print all files under directory `./b` that link to files under directory `./a`.

```bsh
find ./a -type f -exec find ./b -samefile {} -printf "%p hard link to {}" \;
```

An example, given file paths and inode numbers

```bsh
$ find -type f -printf '%p:%i\n' | sort | column -t -s:
./a/f  12977541
./b/f  12977577  # unique file
./c/f  12977541  # points to same file as path ./a/f
#file  inode
```

Run the find command against directory `./a` and `./b` to find any hardlinked files under directory `./c`.

```bsh
 $ find ./a ./b -type f -exec find ./c -samefile {} -printf "%p hard link to {}" \;
 ./c/f hard link to ./a/f
```

This is an *O(n^2)* operation. It will will take a very long time given a large number of files!

Using *GNU find 4.4.2*, *linux 3.13.0-85*, *Ubuntu 14.04*.