# Transmission keeps seeding after downloaded file has been deleted

Tags: filesystems, transmission

I'm using Transmission 2.82 on Xubuntu 14.04, and I noticed that after I deleted the downloaded file permanently from files manager, the job in Transmission was still active and kept seeding, and there was no change in free disk space, so I tried `ls -l /proc/[pid]/fd` and I got this:

`lr-x------ 1 name name 64 May  4 20:39 81 -> /home/downloads/ubuntu-16.04-server-i386.iso (deleted)`

then I redownloaded the file and deleted it with `rm` without deleting the job and the disk space was freed and `ls -l /proc/[pid]/fd` gived no entry related to the file and the job was seeding at 0kb/s.

but to see if it was `rm` that made the difference, I then tried three times delete the downloaded file with `rm` while the job was seeding, and each times I received the same result, the jobs were active and seeding, no change in free disk space, and `ls -l /proc/[pid]/fd` yielded something like:

`lr-x------ 1 name name 64 May  4 20:39 26 -> /home/downloads/ubuntu-16.04-server-i386.iso (deleted)`

and `ls ubuntu-16.04-server-i386.iso` gived:

`ls: cannot access ubuntu-16.04-server-i386.iso: No such file or directory`

I also tried `du -s` and `df /home` in the download folder with another job respectively when:

Job running, file undeleted:
`$ du -sh`
`11G`
`$ df -h /home`
`Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        58G   54G  1.2G  98% /`

Job running, file deleted(with `rm`) (and Transmission keeps seeding after deletion):
`$ du -sh`
`9.9G`
`$ df -h /home`
`Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        58G   54G  1.2G  98% /`

Job deleted, file deleted(in previous step):
`$ du -sh`
`9.9G`
`$ df -h /home`
`Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        58G   54G  1.5G  98% /`

So, what happened to the downloaded file? After I `rm` it, how Transmission is still seeding the job? Is it possible to restore the file? Since `du` and `df` give different outputs, is the file relocated to some other place?

Answer (score 4):

If a program has a file open when you delete it, the kernel only marks it as deleted, but doesn't free the disc space, to avoid breaking the program (it's can't know if the file is important to the function of the program). When the program closes the file the disc space is freed. When that happens you will see the "(deleted)" when you look at `/proc/<pid>/fd` for the process that has the file open.

So this is the kernel being helpful in not removing a file that transmission uses.

If you don't want to share a file using transmission you should remove it from transmission, as far as I remember transmission even has an option for deleting the files as part of stopping to share it.

You can actually restore the file by copying it from `/proc/<pid>/fd/` since it is a link to the file (just one that only exists as long as the process has it open).

```
root@mypc:~# pgrep transmission
1470
root@mypc:~# cd /proc/1470/fd
root@mypc:/proc/1470/fd# ls -l | grep deleted
lr-x------ 1 user user 64 Dec  8 02:55 56 -> /mnt/download/my.file (deleted)
root@mypc:/proc/1470/fd# cp 56 /mnt/download/myrestored.file
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect transmission saves the file to a location unknown to you when downloading. After it is finished it creates a hardlink to that same file in your download folder, but still keeps the hardlink in it's own directory(probably ~/.transmission or something like that).

You can find all hardlinks to the finished download as explained in [How to find all hard links to a given file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/201920/how-to-find-all-hard-links-to-a-given-file) or use this:
Go to `~/Downloads` execute `ls -i` and remember the inode-number for your file. Then you can find the other file by executing `find . -inum NUM` in your home folder.